# Bootstrap navbar dropdowns triggering on non-hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap (with Flat UI) `navbar` before an `iframe` in a "stumbleupon-esk" website I am building.  I'm trying to make the `navbar` have a fixed position, but when I do this the dropdown is triggered when I hover over where the dropdown will appear, but not over the link/list item itself.

[image]

The `Report` dropdown was triggered when I hovered below it, not on it.

Here's the structure of my HTML (in HAML):

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse
  .navbar-inner
    .nav-collapse.collapse
      %ul.nav.pull-left
        %li.dropdown
          %a(href="#")
            %span Report
            %b.caret
          %ul
            %li
              %a#not-startup(href="#" rel="nofollow") Not Startup
              %a#broken-page(href="#" rel="nofollow") Broken Page
              %a#malicious(href="#" rel="nofollow") Malicious
              %a#inappropriate-content(href="#" rel="nofollow") Inappropriate Content
              %a#other(href="#" rel="nofollow") Other
%iframe{:src => ...}
```

And the CSS:

```
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar-inner {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

It works fine without fixed positioning.

Comment: can you post the javascript that initialize the menu ?

Comment: I didn't write it.  The Javascript comes from Bootstrap and applies itself to my HTML with a class of dropdown

Comment: It would be here I guess: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js

Comment: Seems kinda strange, does it behave normally when it is not fixed?

Comment: Yeah, it behaves normally when not fixed position

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found this.

https://github.com/iurevych/Flat-UI/commit/423bef715f56c66c4905f1e7155128b360dfc5af

https://github.com/iurevych/Flat-UI/issues/1

Looks like it caused from a display problem. If you add `display:none;` to `.navbar .nav ul` it will work without easing effects on hover.